# How do I use a custom theme with Runtime Theming in UI Kitten?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow so apologies in advance :)

I am new to React Native and am following this guide for UI Kitten's Runtime Theming so I understand how it works: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/runtime-theming#runtime-theming

I manually installed UI Kitten to a freshly created Expo app (blank, managed workflow) and have been following the guides with no issues. However, I am stuck on the "Runtime Theming" guide.

I do not understand why my **custom theme is being overridden by the default themes** of UI Kitten. I used the Eva Color Generator (https://colors.eva.design/) to create a custom theme and followed the "Branding" guide and it worked perfectly.

I haven't made any changes to the code from the guides. I am not sure where & what I need to change in order to get the app to use my custom theme.

Any help would be appreciated!