# How to use a custom theme with Runtime Theming in UI Kitten?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

This is technically a duplicate but I only found one post about my problem and its over 2 years old with no answer so I decided it would be okay to ask the question again. [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604826/how-do-i-use-a-custom-theme-with-runtime-theming-in-ui-kitten)

I use React-Native and UI-Kitten and wanted to use Runtime Theming in order to switch between dark and light theme

Before I used Runtime theming I followed the Branding guide and used Eva Colors to generate the JSON File which worked completly fine (https://colors.eva.design/) until I used Runtime Theming which for whatever reason seems to override my theme-colors.

I have not made any changes from the guide-code so if you want to see how my code looks you can read these two short guides. [Branding](https://%20https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/branding#branding) [Runtime Theming](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/runtime-theming#runtime-theming)